# Express parent folder access

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi guys I am working on this express aplication. In the top of my express file I wrote this line since all my static files are located in my working directory:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Now I want to send a file that exist in a parent folder of the current folder:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile("../../test.html");
});
```

It didn't work for me, Normally because all static files must exist in the directory defind above, Could I make an exception and make my code work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`express.static` and `res.sendFile` don't know anything about each other. They [happen to share a lot of the same internals](http://evanhahn.com/express-dot-static-deep-dive/) but aren't really related.

You can put `test.html` wherever you want and then reference it using Node's built-in `path` module. For example, if your file structure looks like this:

```
test.html
real-app/
├── app.js
├── node_modules/
└── package.json
```

Then you can send `test.html` like this:

```
var path = require('path');

// ...

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var testHtmlPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'test.html');
  res.sendFile(testHtmlPath);
});
```

---

PS: I wouldn't recommend the way you're sending static files. Serving files from the same directory as your app code (which is what `__dirname` means) can cause [code disclosure](http://www.imperva.com/Resources/Glossary?term=source_code_disclosure), which hackers can use to exploit problems in your code. For example, if a hacker visited this URL:

> http://yourapp.com/app.js

They would be able to see `app.js`, which has all of your application's code. You don't want to reveal that to a hacker! They could also navigate to routes like `/secret-passwords.json` or other similar files.

Typically, static files are placed into a special directory, often called `static` or `public`. You can serve files from this directory like this:

```
var path = require('path');

// ...

var staticFilesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
app.use(express.static(staticFilesPath));
```

In general, you should be pretty careful about sending files that live outside of your app's code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was writing an answer containing the same info but yours is neatly written. Chapeau :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Evan Hahn , for the public folder, I didn't implement yet because I am have started developping my app, but of course I am gonna create it